# Count total extrema in the array in java(Total minima and maxima)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I have to count total maxima and minima in the given array. e.g. we have array = {2,2,3,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,2,5}

so pairs (3,3) and (11,11) are local maxima and pairs(0,1) and (8,9) are local minima. there are no other local extrema in array A. so i have to return total number of minima and maxima.

**suppose we have 4,3,3,5 => then 3,3 will be return as one minima.**

Please help me to find this.

I have tried this code.

Please help me to improve this.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      int[] arr = {64, 14, 52};
      int minima = findLocalMinima(arr);
      System.out.println(minima);
     }

     private int findLocalMinima(int[] arr)
     {
      int minima = 0, maxima = 0;

      for(int i=0;i< arr.length ; i++)
      {
          if(i==0)
          {
              if(arr[1] > arr[0])
              {
                  minima++;
              }
              else if(arr[1] == arr[0]){}
              else
              {
                  maxima++;
              }
          }

          else if(i== arr.length-1)
          {
              if(arr[arr.length-1] > arr[arr.length-2])
              {
                  maxima++;
              }
              else if(arr[arr.length-1] == arr[arr.length-2]){}
              else
              {
                  minima++;
              }

          }
         else
          {
          int first = arr[i-1];
          int middle = arr[i];
          int last = arr[i+1];

          if(middle > first && middle > last)
          {
              maxima++;
          }

          if(middle < first && middle < last)
          {
              minima++;
          }

          if(middle== first)
      }


      return minima+maxima;
     }
     }
}
```

Comment: Your pairs use numbers which don't appear in the data set.  Please clarify this.

Comment: Salvador dali.. any language is okey! I just want the logic.

Comment: I'm wondering this as well. How are you getting (11, 11), (0,1), and (8, 9)

Comment: (11,11) is local maxima because A(11)=5 which is greater than its neighbour that is A(10).

Comment: maxima or minima can be a single element of the array or a slice of elements in the array.

Comment: ah. So you are referring to the cells. Gotcha. ... (Are you referring to the cells?) If this is the case, you might want to replace (3,3) and (11,11) with something like `array[3]` and `array[11]` in your question so it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood you are trying to find the local minima/maxima. For your data: `[2,2,3,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,2,5]`.

[image]

Now you have to ask yourself what do you consider a local minima/maxima - because in [mathematical definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima) the function should be smooth to have it and any spline function is not smooth.

You can approach the task in the following way. Take any number `n0` and check it's right neighbors till the neighbor `nL != n0`. Do the same going to the right. If `nR < n0 > nL` than you have a maxima. Be careful with the edges because on the edge you have to check only one side.

The downside of this is that this can deteriorate to `O(n^2)` solution if all the elements are the same in your array.

To combat this you can in the beginning to remove duplicate neighbors, keeping track of their positions. So if you have an array `[3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4]` you will get a new array `[3, 2, 1, 4]`.

Answer (score 0):

To solve that, you have to keep segments, as long as you don't know if it is really is local minimum/maximum or only an inflection on your slope.

this works with double: it gives you 0, +1 (max), -1 (min):

```
Vector<Double> vd=new Vector<Double> (Arrays.asList(new Double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0,3.0,2.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,4.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,8.0,7.0,4.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0}));
Vector<Integer> vi=utilStat.calculeMinMax(vd);
for (int i=0;i<vd.size();i++)
    System.out.println(vd.get(i)+">"+vi.get(i));

  public static Vector<Integer> calcul_MinMax(Vector<Double> _values)
{
Vector<Integer> result=new Vector<Integer>();   

int size=_values.size();

// IF < 2 value => STOP
if (size<2)
    {
    System.err.println("ERROR : less than 2 values");
    return result;
    }

// first is never min / max
result.add(0);

// last min / max
int last_optimal=0;

// step 1: find plateau /min/max

for (int indice=1;indice<size-1;indice++)
    {
    double value=_values.get(indice);
    // avant et après
    double valeur_before=_values.get(indice-1);
    double valeur_after=_values.get(indice+1);


    // STRICT MAX
    if ((value>valeur_before) && (value>valeur_after))
        {
        result.add(1);
        last_optimal=1;
        }
    else
        // STRICT MIN
    if ((value<valeur_before) && (value<valeur_after))
        {
        result.add(-1);
        last_optimal=-1;
        }
    else
        // BEGIN MAX POTENTIAL
    if ((value>valeur_before) && (value==valeur_after))
        {
        result.add(2);
        last_optimal=2; 
        }
    else
        // BEGIN MIN POTENTIAL
    if ((value<valeur_before) && (value==valeur_after))
        {
        result.add(-2);
        last_optimal=-2;        
        }
    else
        // SUITE MAX MIN
    if ((value==valeur_before) && (value==valeur_after))
        {
        result.add(last_optimal);
        // last_optimal keeps the same
        }
    else
        // END MAX POTENTIAL
    if ((value==valeur_before) && (value>valeur_after))
        {
        // EITHER WE WERE REALLY ON A MAX
        if (last_optimal==2)
            {
            result.add(2);
            // all precedents reset to 1
            for (int j=indice;j>=0;j--)
                {   
                if (result.get(j)==2)
                    result.set(j, 1);
                else break;
                }
            }
        else
            // EITHER PLATEAU
            {
            result.add(2);
            // all precedents reset to 0
            for (int j=indice;j>=0;j--)
                {   
                if (result.get(j)!=0)
                    result.set(j, 0);
                else break;
                }   
            }
        last_optimal=0;
        }
    else
        // END  MIN POTENTIAL
    if ((value==valeur_before) && (value<valeur_after))
        {
        //  EITHER WE WERE REALLY ON A MIN
        if (last_optimal==-2)
            {
            result.add(-2);
            //  all precedents reset to -1
            for (int j=indice;j>=0;j--)
                {   
                if (result.get(j)==-2)
                    result.set(j, -1);
                else break;
                }
            }
        else
            // EITHER PLATEAU
            {
            result.add(-2);
            //  all precedents reset to 0
            for (int j=indice;j>=0;j--)
                {   
                if (result.get(j)!=0)
                    result.set(j, 0);
                else break;
                }   
            }
        last_optimal=0;
        }

    else
        // LAST CASE: INVERSION
        {
        result.add(0);
        last_optimal=0;
        }
    }

// LAST IS NEVER min / max
result.add(0);

return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public int solution(int[] A)
        {
            int len = A.Length;
            int cnt = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0 || A[i - 1] < A[i])
                {
                    int j = i;
                    while (j < len && A[j] == A[i])
                        j++;

                    if (j == len || A[j] < A[i])
                        cnt++;
                }
                if (i == 0 || A[i - 1] > A[i])
                {
                    int j = i;

                    while (j < len && A[j] == A[i])
                        j++;

                    if (j == len || A[j] > A[i])
                        cnt++;
                }
            }
            return cnt;
        }
```